# React Native: Animated node with tag 1 does not exists

Tags: react-native, webrtc

I keep getting the error:

```
Animated node with tag 1 does not exists
```

Im not event using the Animated Tag in any of my code so why do I get this error.

This is my package.json

```
        {
      "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start",
        "android": "expo start --android",
        "ios": "expo start --ios",
        "web": "expo start --web",
        "eject": "expo eject"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
        "expo": "~40.0.0",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "react": "17.0.1",
        "react-dom": "16.13.1",
        "react-native": "^0.64.0-rc.4",
        "react-native-android-permissions": "^1.0.2",
        "react-native-device-uuid": "^1.2.0",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
        "react-native-incall-manager": "^3.3.0",
        "react-native-paper": "^4.7.2",
        "react-native-peerjs": "^1.0.4",
        "react-native-permissions": "^3.0.1",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
        "react-native-screens": "^2.15.2",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
        "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
        "react-native-webrtc": "^1.89.1",
        "react-native-webview": "^11.0.0",
        "socket.io-client": "^4.0.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.9.0"
      },
      "private": true
    }
```

if you require more files, please ask?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just go down 1 version, so react-native: `^0.63.0`

Expo is currently not supporting react-native `0.64.0`+

Expo:

> Today we’re announcing the release of Expo SDK 41. SDK 41 includes React Native 0.63, the same version as in SDK 40. Thank you to everyone that helped with beta testing. Curious why we didn’t include the recently released React Native 0.64? Learn more.)

UPDATE: doing `expo upgrade` looks to also fix the issue. Just worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and this fixed it for me:

```
npm install https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.4.tar.gz
```